# Conditions in Where predicate before join vs in Where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-6

I was joining two objects in `Entity Framwork` and putting all the conditions in `Where` clause. But my boss said to put all other conditions in `Where` predicate that would be more efficient. like below, first one is my version-

```
var query = from ct in dbContext.ClaimTrackings
                                            join cts in dbContext.ClaimTrackingStatus
                                            on ct.ID equals cts.ClaimTrackingID
                                            where ct.CenterID == centerID && ct.ClaimMonth == SharePointClaimProcessingData.ClaimMonth && ct.ClaimYear == SharePointClaimProcessingData.ClaimYear
                                            select cts;




var query = from ct in dbContext.ClaimTrackings.Where(p => p.CenterID == centerID && p.ClaimMonth == SharePointClaimProcessingData.ClaimMonth && p.ClaimYear == SharePointClaimProcessingData.ClaimYear)
                                            join cts in dbContext.ClaimTrackingStatus
                                            on ct.ID equals cts.ClaimTrackingID
                                            select cts;
```

I cannot see the generated script as this code can only run on production.
I am not sure which one is more efficient. So please explain.

Comment: It looks like they would likely generate the same or equivalent SQL statements - have you checked the SQL that's generated when you run these queries? Anything that happens before enumeration will be translated to a single store expression, so there's a good likelihood that since these return identical results the query/plan would be the same. I can try out a similar set of joins for you

Comment: See my updated post, I cannot run it locally due to some limitations.

Comment: Maybe I can create a sample project and run it when I get some time. But I would also like to hear some expert comments.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've done some testing and what I thought is correct - since the results are the same, moving the where clause higher up makes no difference at all - certainly for SQL server.

Just ran these two queries in a context for one of our client apps (just swapped out your entity names for mine):

```
        var query = from ct in _context.Batches
                    join cts in _context.Blends
                    on ct.BatchId equals cts.BatchId
                    where ct.BatchId == 13349 && ct.CreatedBy == "Automation"
                    select cts;

        var query2 = from ct in _context.Batches.Where(x => x.BatchId == 13349 && x.CreatedBy == "Automation")
                     join cts in _context.Blends
                     on ct.BatchId equals cts.BatchId
                     select cts;
```

Equivalent queries:

```
SELECT 
[Extent2].[BlendId] AS [BlendId], 
[Extent2].[BatchId] AS [BatchId], 
[Extent2].[BlendNumber] AS [BlendNumber], 
[Extent2].[ProductCode] AS [ProductCode], 
[Extent2].[TargetQuantity] AS [TargetQuantity], 
[Extent2].[RecipeDescription] AS [RecipeDescription], 
[Extent2].[BlenderId] AS [BlenderId], 
[Extent2].[TestingSetDescription] AS [TestingSetDescription], 
[Extent2].[SieveDefaultDescription] AS [SieveDefaultDescription], 
[Extent2].[ReblendTime] AS [ReblendTime], 
[Extent2].[Operator] AS [Operator], 
[Extent2].[ProcessedBy] AS [ProcessedBy], 
[Extent2].[KeggedBy] AS [KeggedBy], 
[Extent2].[ApprovedBy] AS [ApprovedBy], 
[Extent2].[ActualQuantity] AS [ActualQuantity], 
[Extent2].[TestedBy] AS [TestedBy], 
[Extent2].[TestStatus] AS [TestStatus], 
[Extent2].[ApprovedQuantity] AS [ApprovedQuantity], 
[Extent2].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate]
FROM  [dbo].[Batches] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Blends] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[BatchId] = [Extent2].[BatchId]
WHERE (13349 = [Extent1].[BatchId]) AND (N'Automation' = [Extent1].[CreatedBy])
```

And

```
SELECT 
[Extent2].[BlendId] AS [BlendId], 
[Extent2].[BatchId] AS [BatchId], 
[Extent2].[BlendNumber] AS [BlendNumber], 
[Extent2].[ProductCode] AS [ProductCode], 
[Extent2].[TargetQuantity] AS [TargetQuantity], 
[Extent2].[RecipeDescription] AS [RecipeDescription], 
[Extent2].[BlenderId] AS [BlenderId], 
[Extent2].[TestingSetDescription] AS [TestingSetDescription], 
[Extent2].[SieveDefaultDescription] AS [SieveDefaultDescription], 
[Extent2].[ReblendTime] AS [ReblendTime], 
[Extent2].[Operator] AS [Operator], 
[Extent2].[ProcessedBy] AS [ProcessedBy], 
[Extent2].[KeggedBy] AS [KeggedBy], 
[Extent2].[ApprovedBy] AS [ApprovedBy], 
[Extent2].[ActualQuantity] AS [ActualQuantity], 
[Extent2].[TestedBy] AS [TestedBy], 
[Extent2].[TestStatus] AS [TestStatus], 
[Extent2].[ApprovedQuantity] AS [ApprovedQuantity], 
[Extent2].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate]
FROM  [dbo].[Batches] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Blends] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[BatchId] = [Extent2].[BatchId]
WHERE (13349 = [Extent1].[BatchId]) AND (N'Automation' = [Extent1].[CreatedBy])
```

Unsurprisingly they are identical. I can't give you the exact mechanism EF uses to generate the query but basically you are joining two tables and filtering so the translation to a store query gives you the same result, most likely because of the way it looks at the entities involved

So, in this case, second guessing your boss (something I do all the time) was correct :)